# Python For Loop and API

Tags: python, pandas, api, loops

I am trying to pull from an API and practice my loops but for some reason I cannot get it to work. I end up with a blank dataframe. The result is:

"Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []"

I would add error details if there were an error. If I run the code and only print df3, I get what I want for the last iteration which is Year_Month,Measure,Power,State.

|  | Year_Month | Measure | Power | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 202103 | 4488.75084 | ELEC | AR |
| 1 | 202102 | 4482.13587 | ELEC | AR |
| 2 | 202101 | 5183.46301 | ELEC | AR |
| 3 | 202012 | 4580.98863 | ELEC | AR |
| 4 | 202011 | 3831.74831 | ELEC | AR |
| 238 | 200105 | 3690.53100 | ELEC | AR |
| 239 | 200104 | 3349.77400 | ELEC | AR |
| 240 | 200103 | 3125.26100 | ELEC | AR |
| 241 | 200102 | 3372.02000 | ELEC | AR |
| 242 | 200101 | 3903.32300 | ELEC | AR |

However, I obviously want each loop to append to the last dataframe. Something like this...

|  | Year_Month | Measure | Power | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 202103 | 4488.75084 | ELEC | NH |
| 1 | 202102 | 4482.13587 | ELEC | NH |
| 2 | 202101 | 5183.46301 | ELEC | NH |
| 3 | 202012 | 4580.98863 | ELEC | NH |
| 4 | 202011 | 3831.74831 | ELEC | NH |
| 500 | 202103 | 4488.75084 | ELEC | AR |
| 501 | 202102 | 4482.13587 | ELEC | AR |
| 502 | 202101 | 5183.46301 | ELEC | AR |
| 503 | 202012 | 4580.98863 | ELEC | AR |
| 504 | 202011 | 3831.74831 | ELEC | AR |

The commented-out section in my code below works but I'd like to use the for loop to pick up the data for each state in the state list.

Also, sleeping does not help either.

```
import urllib3
from urllib3 import request
import certifi
import json
import pandas as pd

http = urllib3.PoolManager(
       cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
       ca_certs=certifi.where())

API_KEY='MYKEY'
State=['NH','MA','AK','AZ','AR']#,'CA','CO','CT','DE','DC','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA','KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND','OH','OK','OR','PA','PR','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY']
Stated='NH'
Powered='ELEC'
Frame=pd.DataFrame([])

#url = 'http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key='+API_KEY+'&series_id='+Powered+'.GEN.ALL-'+Stated+'-99.M'
#r = http.request('GET', url)
#d = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
#df = pd.json_normalize(d, 'series')
#df2=df.explode('data')
#Frame=pd.DataFrame(df2["data"].to_list(), columns=['Year_Month', 'Measure'])
#Frame['Power']=Powered
#Frame['State']=Stated

for i in State:
    url = 'http://api.eia.gov/series/?api_key='+API_KEY+'&series_id='+Powered+'.GEN.ALL-'+i+'-99.M'
    r = http.request('GET', url)
    d = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
    df = pd.json_normalize(d, 'series')
    df2=df.explode('data')
    df3=pd.DataFrame(df2["data"].to_list(), columns=['Year_Month', 'Measure'])
    df3['Power']=Powered
    df3['State']=i
    Frame.append(df3, ignore_index = True)

print(Frame)
```

Comment: You should remove the `API_KEY` from your question. Seems like something that could be misused.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I used 10min mail to generate that key to post but probably still not great to have a loose key out there for anyone to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.append` returns the appended the DataFrame so you want to change the last line of your loop to the following:

```
Frame = Frame.append(df3, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! I don't have enough reputation to mark it as the answer haha!

Comment: @RyanG - Lol don't worry about it ;)

Comment: @RyanG The reputation required to accept an answer is `1`. Anyone who can _ask_ a question can accept an answer. (See [What does it mean to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for information)